# Using windows environment variables in R's setwd()

Tags: r, environment-variables

I would like to use windows environment variables in R's `setwd()` command, so I can use the same script at work and at my home computer, because I have a variable `"%ONEDRIVE%"` set for my cloud folder, which are at different locations on my different computers.

I have set up the variables, and Windows Explorer opens the folders fine from the variable, however if I feed

```
setwd("%ONEDRIVE%")
```

to R, it states

```
*Error in setwd("%ONEDRIVE%") : cannot change working directory*.
```

Is it unavailable in R, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Sys.getenv` to pass the *value*  of the environment variable to `setwd`:

```
Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
#[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2"
setwd(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"))
getwd()
#[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set up the path for windows environment Variable in following fashion
(Double \ \ instead of single \ ):

```
C:\ \Users\ \XYZ\ \OneDrive
```

Once environment variable is set try following commands

## Validate Environment variable

```
Sys.getenv("OneDrive")
```

[1] "C:\ \Users\ \XYZ\ \OneDrive"

## Assign Environment variable

```
setwd(Sys.getenv("OneDrive"))
```

## Check your working directory

```
getwd()

[1] "C:/Users/XYZ/OneDrive"
```

Comment: *Why* would you suggest setting the path in the environment variable that way? This answer would benefit from an explanation of the purpose of that step. Otherwise, this answer is the same as the [older answer by Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33689791/4200548).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are using the wrong syntax `%`

`setwd("%ONEDRIVE%"`)

--> This is worng
correct one is -> `setwd("ONEDRIVE")`